# What is the difference between these functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the book Jquery in Action, and it mentions these three functions when talking about removing conflict with other libraries. However, I don't know what the difference is between them and do not understand the book's explanation.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    alert('I"m ready!');
});

var $ = 'Hi!';
jQuery(function() {
    alert('$ = ' + $);
});

var $ = 'Hi!';
jQuery(function($) {
    alert('$ = ' + $);
});
```

Does anyone know what the difference is? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a simplified version it might be more understandable. The first ready function is not doing much more than alerting. The other two are interesting.

Functions have scope, which means that when you use a variable inside one, it will go up in the hierarchy until it has been found.

In your second ready function, the `$` will go up to the `Hi!` as there is no other `$` if you go up starting inside the function.

However, in the third ready block, the `$` will not go to the `Hi!` because it has a definition that is closer - the one passed as an argument (`function($) {`). This `$` will be the jQuery function (i.e. in that function `$ == jQuery`) as this is how jQuery's ready feature is implemented.

So:

```
var $ = 'Hi!';

jQuery(function() {
    alert('$ = ' + $); // in this scope, $ will refer to the 'Hi!'
});

jQuery(function($) {   // the $ here will 'shadow' the $ defined as 'Hi!'
    alert('$ = ' + $); // in this scope, $ will refer to jQuery
});
```

Now your question is about conflict with other libraries. Other libraries (Prototype for example) also use the `$` symbol as it is a convenient shortcut to calling the library. If you use the last ready function you provided, you can be **sure** that inside that function, `$` will refer to jQuery as jQuery passes itself to that function (as the first argument).

In the second ready function, `$` might also have been set to Prototype, for example, and you are not sure whether you are calling jQuery with `$`. In your example, it was `Hi!` and not jQuery. In case it's Prototype it's the same thing. Consider:

```
// Prototype is loaded here, $ is referring to Prototype

jQuery(function() {
    $('selector').addClass('something'); // Oops - you're calling Prototype with $!
});
```

On the other hand:

```
// Prototype is loaded here, $ is referring to Prototype

jQuery(function($) { // this $ is shadowing Prototype's $, this $ is jQuery
    $('selector').addClass('something'); // Yay - you're calling jQuery with $
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when you type `jQuery(function ($) { ...` the $ is simply an alias to the jQuery object. You could in fact use any legal identifier instead of $, and this would still be an alias to the jQuery object.

In the second example, alert will say '$ = Hi!' because in that case the $ is pointing to the var declared just above the function.

The third example effectively masks the $ declared above the function because the $ will resolve to the jQuery object inside the function.

I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: @Beefyhalo--Does the '$' take on special meaning if it is already within the `jQuery()` handler?

That is to say, does the argument passed within `jQuery(function(argument) {...})` still (effectively) resolve to the same thing as the `$`?

Comment: jQuery will assign itself to the first argument in a jQuery handler. Whatever the name of the first argument is, jQuery will be assigned to it. So for `jQuery(function(argument) {...`, `jQuery(function($) {...`, and `jQuery(function(someOtherArgument) {...`, are all equivalent in the sense that `argument === $ === someOtherArgument`

Answer (score 1):

The first code block declares a ready handler that is executed once the DOM hass been fully loaded. It merely produces an alert box.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    alert('I"m ready!');
});
```

The second code block also declares a ready handler, but it is demonstrating a conflict. The `$` variable has been deliberately been set to a string (this could occur from a conflicting js library) and therefore cannot be used as the jQuery object. Within the scope of the handler function, `$` remains assigned to the string and so the alert displays `$ = Hi!`.

```
var $ = 'Hi!';
jQuery(function() {
    alert('$ = ' + $);
});
```

The third code block also declares a ready handler, but it declares a local `$` parameter. The jQuery object passes itself into the ready handler as the first parameter and so within the function scope, `$` refers to the jQuery object and the alert will print `$ = ...`, where `...` is a representation of the jQuery object.

```
var $ = 'Hi!';
jQuery(function($) {
    alert('$ = ' + $);
});
```